# using total derivative to approximate changes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the function $ f(x,y,z) = xyz$  with $y = x^2 $, $z = \sqrt[3]{x} $

The initial values are $ (27, 729, 3) $

I want to compute the total derivative of f wrt x and use that to approximate the change in f due to an increase in x by 0.1 units.

I am confused because my answer is not equivalent to what I get when I simply make 
$f = x^{7/2} $ and compute $ f'(x)*0.1 $.

The two different methods should give the same answer, so I think I am making a mistake with my calculation of the total derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point given $(27,729,3)$ does not satisfy the condition on $z$, so I will use $z=\sqrt[3]{x}$ instead of $\sqrt{x}$.

Firstly, consider $f(x,y,z)=xyz$, with $y=x^2$ and $z=\sqrt[3]{x}$. Then
$$
df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz=yz\,dx+xz\,dy+xy\,dz.
$$
We are given $dx=0.1$, but we need to calculate $dy$ and $dz$. Using the same approach,
$$
\begin{align}
dy&=\frac{dy}{dx}dx=2x\,dx,\\
dz&=\frac{dz}{dx}dx=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}\,dx.
\end{align}
$$
This gives $dy=5.4$ and $dz=1/270$. Substituting all of this information into $df$ gives $df=729$.

The second method, with the adjusted $z$ function gives $f(x)=x^{10/3}$. Its differential is
$$
df=\frac{df}{dx}dx=\frac{10}{3}x^{7/3}\,dx.
$$
Substituting $x=27$ and $dx=0.1$ gives $df=729$.